# add 1 to a single element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, increment

There is an array containing numbers and I want to increment only one number in the array

```
let array = [1, 3, 5]
// just add 1 in the second element of the array and return that array
// array = [1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: How about `++array[1];`?

Comment: or `array[1]++;`

Answer (score 0):

Both `array[1]++` and `array[1] = array[1] + 1` will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can increment another number using the Push(); method:

```
let array = [1,2,3];
array.push(yourNumber);
```

Comment: The question is about adding the number of 1 to the second element of an array. This answer appends a number to an array, e.g.,
array.push(6) //results in [1, 3, 5, 6]